# Detecting subtle signals embedded in random patterns?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Suppose one million random 10 digit binary numbers have been generated:

$$1011010101$$
$$1110010100$$
$$0110001010$$
$$...$$

A "bug" in the generator code is such that the $3^{rd}$ and $7^{th}$ digit of the sequence have an "extra" conditional algorithm tucked in:

> If the parity of all digits to the left of the $3^{rd}$ digit is odd, and the parity of all digits to the right of the $7^{th}$ digit is even, then there is a 10% chance of the $7^{th}$ digit morphing to match the $3^{rd}$ digit value.

$$01\color{red}0010\color{red}1110$$

Suppose this bug is unknown to us.

Is there a systematic statistical way to discover the inherent non-randomness in these set of 1 million numbers, and if so, is there a way to discover which digits are problematic and the exact bug algorithm that produces them?

Comment: If you have no suspicions regarding that particular bug, it seems awfully hard to catch.

Comment: Systematic way that tries to catch any non-randomness? I don't think so. There are just so extremely many ways the system can be non-random, you can't hope to cover them all, and each test has to be tailor-made to the kind of non-randomness it tries to detect. Systematic way that tries to catch non-randomness of the kind "One of the ten bits is equal to one of the other ten bits slightly more often than $50\%$ of the time", sure. Given enough samples, you could find a way to systematically detect those with decent probability.

Comment: @Arthur yes, we can find the digit $3^{rd}$ and $7^{th}$ using occurence correlation. Once we find the anomaly, will there be a way to discover *what* algorithm causes this manifestation of the anomaly?

Comment: But are you seriously going to compute every possible pair correlation?  What about triples?   Groups of $91$?   It certainly makes sense to run your "random" numbers through a suite of tests, but it will always be easy to find bugs that would elude any given suite of detectors.

Comment: In one of the early machine computations of $\pi$, a sporadic bug was found that was eventually traced to a single cleaning person who came in once every couple of weeks and who insisted on using carbon tetrachloride despite it being banned.  This was discovered by one of the scientists who had started sleeping in the computer room in a last ditch effort to nail the bug.  Isolated, sporadic bugs can be brutal to track down.

Comment: Engineers have developed the list of [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) that good random number generators should pass. @lulu How did that cleaning person get involved in the computation of $\pi\,?$

Comment: @lulu this "needle in a haystack" property could be used as a discreet signal sending method between two knowing parties, could it not? say, send 1 million random numbers each time, if bug A is present then it's 0, if bug B is present then it's 1.

Comment: @KurtG  The computers filled a room and that room needed to be cleaned.  As I understand it,  there were strict protocols attached to the cleaning and these were mostly (but not always) followed.  The cleaning fluid interfered with some of the capacitors.

Comment: @James  Absolutely.  And you can easily send messages by changing a few pixels in a picture of a cat.  If you don't have access to the original picture, it's effectively impossible to catch such a minor change.   Not sure I see the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @KurtG.  Which of those tests do you imagine would catch such an isolated bug as the one described here?  those things are set up to spot bias in large systems...not single bit corruption.

Comment: @lulu Fantastic story. Apparently not only quantum computers need to be shielded from their environment :) About the Diehard tests: no idea. Just wanted to make OP aware if that wasn't the case already.

Comment: @KurtG.  Seriously.  Can you imagine how frustrating it must have been to notice that the $5$ million$^{th}$ or whatever digit of $\pi$ was different every other Tuesday?  I like large scale bugs.  They are easy to spot and easy to trace to their origin.  Isolated, rare, problems are the Devil's work.

Comment: @lulu one advantage might be that, dictionary-type cat picture comparison will degrade its secrecy with each repeated use, while bug in random numbers can be used indefinitely without degrading its secrecy (?)

Comment: There's an ambiguity in your description which Henry has interpreted differently in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682990/detecting-subtle-signals-embedded-in-random-patterns/4683145#4683145) to the way I read it.  Are the strings to the "extra conditional algorithm" are applied only those of the form $$\ 11abcde000\ ,\ $$ as Henry interpreted it, or is it applied to all strings of any of the forms\begin{align}&01abcde000\\&10abcde000\\&01abcde011\\&10abcde011\\&01abcde101\\&10abcde101 \\&01abcde110\\&10abcde110\ ,\end{align}as I interpreted it (after correction)?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera as i happen to write it in the question, i meant the second case (ie. parity of digits 1+2 odd, and party of digits 8+9+10 even), then in 10% of cases, digit 7 will be changed to match digit 3. But i am open to any analysis using different bug algorithms... :)

Answer (score 3):

Most of your $1024$ strings will be expected to appear about $\frac{10^6}{2^{10}} \approx 977$ times (with a standard deviation about $31$) but for some the expected number is $10\%$ lower about $879$ and others $10\%$ higher about $1074$.

So if you did something like a chi-squared analysis then it would not surprise me if you were quite likely in this example to reject a hypothesis that all $1024$ strings/values were equally likely to appear.

If you then looked at the least and most common strings/values, you might spot that a disproportionate number of both were of the binary form $11xxxxx000$, i.e. in decimal at least $768$ and a multiple of $8$.  It might take longer to estimate the further detail.

Here is an example in R:

```
set.seed(2023)
sims <- sample(0:(2^10-1), 10^6, replace=TRUE)
unirv <- runif(10^6)
simsadjusted <- sims + ifelse(unirv > 0.1, 0, 
    ifelse(sims %/% (2^7) == 7 & sims %% (2^4) == 0, 8, 0) + 
    ifelse(sims %/% (2^7) == 6 & sims %% (2^4) == 8, -8, 0))   

counts <- table(sims)
chisq.test(counts)             # before adjustment
#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  counts
# X-squared = 1028.4, df = 1023, p-value = 0.4465

countsadjusted <- table(simsadjusted)
chisq.test(countsadjusted)          # after adjustment
#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  countsadjusted
# X-squared = 1351.1, df = 1023, p-value = 1.898e-11

sortcountsadjusted  <- sort(countsadjusted)

names(head(sortcountsadjusted, 10))    # ten least common
# "872"  "840"  "792"  "896"  "776"  "1008" "856"  "976"  "912"  "808" 

names(tail(sortcountsadjusted, 10))    # ten most common
# "296"  "832"  "334"  "984"  "1016" "936"  "920"  "968"  "904"  "864"
```

Comment: (+1) In my opinion, a sample of $\ 10^6\ $ would be large enough to spot also that the higher and lower frequency numbers were the $256$  with $\ b_1\text{ xor }b_2=0\ $ and $\ b_8\text{ xor }b_9\text{ xor }b_{10}=1\ $ (where $\ b_i\ $ is the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ bit of the number), that the higher frequency numbers were the $128$ of these with $\ b_3\text{ xor }$$\,b_7=0\ $ and that the lower frequency ones were the $128$ of them with $\ b_3\text{ xor }$$\,b_7=1\ $, not, of course, with a very high degree of certainty, but at least as a good working hypothesis.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: I think the tests apply to "all the digits" left and right so are $b_1\text{ and }b_2=1$ with $b_8\text{ or }b_9\text{ or }b_{10}=0$ so rather tighter than your suggestion.  A sample $10^6$ is very like to show something is going on but note that in my particular example $334_{10}=0101001110_2$ was the $8$th most common value through sampling noise so I did not get perfect separation.

Comment: Rerunning my code on a different system annoyingly gives me different results despite the seed (above was run on rdrr.io)  but the $11$th most common value using my PC was $252_{10}=0011111100_2$ so illustrating the same issue.

Comment: I wouldn't expect perfect separation with a sample of a million. But the frequencies of the higher and lower frequency numbers should differ from $\ \frac{10^6}{1024}\ $ by about $\ 3\ $ standard deviation, so I would expect it to be possible to identify the pattern. I do recognise, however, that when you've been told the pattern, armchair speculation about what you might be able to do is much easier than doing it in practise.

Comment: I didn't recognise the ambiguity in the description of the process until you pointed it out, although I did think it was a rather strange way of saying what I took it to mean.  To me, however,  it seems like an equally strange way of saying what you took it to mean, so I definitely think the meaning needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Henry this gets me thinking if the bug gets even more obscure, say IF parity of digits 1+2 is odd AND parity of digits 2+5+7 is even AND parity of digits 8+3 is odd AND parity of digits 9+4+6 is even THEN there is 10% chance of digit 7 morphing into digit 3 AND if so a further 10% chance of digit 2 morphing into digit 7. I wonder can Easter eggs like this be found without preknowing the pattern?